# Error in code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
  double t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

  int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  System.out.println("r = " + r + ", t = " + t);
```

This part of the code is not compiling. I couldn't find what's wrong.

Error Code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `args` contains the supplied command-line arguments as an array of String objects.

In other words, if you run your program as `java DemoMain one two` then args will contain `["one", "two"]`.

In your case you are not passing any args which result in `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

You are not passing the value of args. Try to pass the value through the command line you.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.out.println(args[0]);
        double t;
        t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

        double r;
         r = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: compile before running the class `javac DemoMain.java` Try to pass the arguments while running the Java Class as `java DemoMain 1`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated within your Post Title is in contradiction with the error you indicated within your actual post. The Error in the title indicates you are accepting more than one argument whereas the first argument was successful but there was no second argument. The error indicated within your post body indicates that there was no argument supplied at all. Which is it?

Based on the error indicated within your post,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

there are no arguments detected. In other words the args[] String Array contains nothing (0 elements)...no arguments were supplied at startup from the Terminal Command Prompt.

To save-guard your application from this situation you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Were arguments supplied? 
    if (args.length == 0) {
        // No... 
        System.out.println("Failure! - No Argument Supplied!");
        return;
    }
    /* Is the argument supplied a string representation of a signed 
       or unsigned Integer or double/float numerical value?      */
    else if (!args[0].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        // No...
        System.out.println("Failure! - Invalid Numerical Argument Supplied!");
        return;
    }

    double t = 0.0d;
    int r = 0;

    // Has a double or float value been supplied?
    if (args[0].contains(".")) {
        // Yup ... So let's convert to double.
        t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    }
    else {   
        // Nope ... So let's convert to Integer (int).
        r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    // Display the result in Console Window.
    System.out.println("r = " + r + ", t = " + t);
}
```

You will also need to take note that you can not pass a string representation of a [floating point value](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/floating-point-data-types-in-java/) to the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method. This is because the period (**.**) is considered an alpha character (like a whitespace or the letter A) which the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method will not accept. If you try a **NumberFormatException** is thrown and your application halts in failure. The **Integer.parseInt()** method will however accept a value prefixed with a `-` or `+` character (ie:  **Integer.parseInt("+50")**. We've also taken this into consideration in the above code example (read the comments in code).